# Which machine to get for a home server?

Tags: home-server, web-hosting

I want to have a server at home. Mainly for few projects, blog(wordpress) and maybe other web resources. I want to have it very low power consumable, so I am thinking getting Acer Aspire Revo 3600, but I am not pro at server hardware stuff. As an desktop/mobile it is a great solution for working (not gaming). So maybe someone good at it and could advice me what machine should I get? Or its better to buy a remote server from somewhere else? Maybe there is some web page resources which could help me with this decision and other server hosting/establishing problems? :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a static ip - then go for a normal Atom machine (Asus eeeBox + many many others) (ION is entirely optional, and will not really increase the performance of the tasks you are setting out to achieve). In fact, given the small price difference between an Atom SFF desktop, and an Atom notebook, you might want to just go for an Atom notebook to be your home server - it makes it much easier to troubleshoot anyway with its built-in screen (just in case you can't RDP or SSH into the machine and have to drag a monitor over).

However, if this machine is primarily for serving content over the web to your audience, etc, I'd very much recommend you to get a hosting service (shared hosting, really cheap anyway). Especially so if your home Internet connection is on a Dynamic IP plan. Also, your bandwidth have to be sizable to support many concurrent users.

Try [GoDaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com), or just search for a webhost that suits your needs (make sure to also do a search for " sucks downtime" to ensure that they are reliable.

Start with the cheapest hosting plan first - you can always upgrade later. Make sure they have features such as MySQL and PHP support - I also recommend Linux hosts.

Comment: Arent u missplaced dynamic ip and static ip? with static ip my pc will not be reachable from outside. and with dynamic i can host watever i want at my place :)

Comment: Well the common definition when I say I'm on a "Static IP" broadband plan, is that my IP address on the Internet is never changed - thus people will always be able to reach me at the same number.

Conversely, Dynamic IP (which is what most people are on), their IP Address on the Internet changes regularly.

Don't get it confused with internal networks - I am referring to the IP address your ISP assign you, whether it's dynamic or static.

And you can host whatever you want at your place whether it is static or dynamic.

Comment: And also, internally, it's better if your server is also assigned a static ip by your router, then get your router to forward all common web requests protocols (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc) to that static ip. It is less reliable if your server is on dynamic IP.